# How to output the value of a selected array key

Tags: php

getting a json file from an API now i need to use values in the array
here's an example assuming

```
<?php
     $jsonData = {"responseCode":"8876","responseDetail":"success","accessToken":"098826sdftyajjla;"}

     $array = json_encode($jsonData);
     echo $array['accessToken'];
```

Comment: Please find the below code to fetch the "accessToken" value                     <?php 
         $jsonData = '{"responseCode":"8876","responseDetail":"success","accessToken":"098826sdftyajjla"}';

         $array = json_decode($jsonData);
         echo $array->{'accessToken'};
    ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot access json_encoded data using arrays you must have to decode the json first and then you can access values e.g

```
$json_data = '{"response_code":200,"response_status":"success","accessToken":"abcdef"}';
$data = json_decode($json_data);
echo $data->accessToken;
```

Comment: Thanks bro, you're the man...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
    <?php 
         $jsonData = '{"responseCode":"8876","responseDetail":"success","accessToken":"098826sdftyajjla;"}';
         $array = json_decode($jsonData);
         print_r($array->accessToken );
?>
```